# Is it possible to access to google translate api for free?

Tags: google-translate

Google only gives access to their translate API with payment but I want free access.

Is it possible to use Google's translate API for free? What are the alternatives?

Comment: yes, it is possible. There is example how to do it with java - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159904/7179509

Comment: Can we reopen this, please? I have [a solution](https://klesun.github.io/entry/google_translate_api_spreadsheet/) that allows making requests directly from users browser, without intermediate proxy, even without libraries. [Source](https://github.com/klesun/klesun.github.io/blob/master/entry/google_translate_api_spreadsheet/src/GoogleTranslateTk.js).

Answer (score 56):

Yes, you can use GT for free. See the [post with explanation](https://ctrlq.org/code/19909-google-translate-api).
And look at [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api).

**UPD 19.03.2019** Here is [a version for browser](https://github.com/cjvnjde/google-translate-api-browser) on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah, but is it legal that way?

Comment: @Sebastian No, it isn't.

Comment: Does Google do anything about people using it in their apps?

Comment: Thomas why do you think so?
@Sebastian no, they don't.

Comment: @Londeren how to use GT in android project for free?

Comment: @HammadNasir I think it's possible to adapt this solution for android (JS to Java)

Comment: @HammadNasir you can take the code from https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api and rewrite it from JS to Java and then use it in your android app

Comment: @HammadNasir sorry, but I don't know Java

Comment: @hammadNasir It is possible with a http client in android and get info with (for example) a json response from an api url with get or post parameters.

Comment: No, you can't! After a while, Google will detect suspicious traffic from your IP and you will get 503 error.

Comment: Here you have an Android Java implementation: https://pastebin.com/A96mfdBZ

Comment: can we translate english to sanskrit? i.e. text to text translation

Comment: @Anatoly -- not if you call it from the front end :)

Comment: @ThomasRones Genious