# How to use java-google-translate-text-to-speech api?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I read one answer here ([How to use Google Translate API in my Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147284/how-to-use-google-translate-api-in-my-java-application)) and started to use java-google-translate-text-to-speech api as it is free.

But when I use this api in a standalone java file, I am facing an issue : "Your client does not have permission to get URL /translate_a/t from this server. That’s all we know." HTTP Reponse Code 403-Forbidden error.
Do I need to use API key to use this api ?
Is there any sample code which uses API key ?
I am posting a question for the first time so apologies if the formatting is incorrect.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

The official API is 20$ for 1 million characters (proportionally), so you could still consider using it as it's quite cheap. 
The project you're referring to hasn't been updated in a long time, so it could just be broken due to changes by Google....

In the comments they also referenced [this](https://github.com/wihoho/java-google-translate-text-to-speech) project, you could try using this, but I would still recommend the official API's.

Comment: Thank you Serge !! Seems that I will have to use the official api.