# How to translate words in android studio app?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-translate

I have used geocoder to get the address through the location. However, the city name is in English and I want to show it in Arabic.

This is the code to get the address :

```
public String getAddress(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
        String city = "";
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {

                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); 
                city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); 

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return city;
    }
```

And then this is where I show the city name in a TextView :

```
String country_and_city = getAddress(latitude, longitude);

TextView city_name = findViewById(R.id.city);  
city_name.setText(country_and_city);
```

Here, the city name will be displayed in English, how can I translate it or use other methods to show it in Arabic? For example, maybe using google-translate api or something if that is even possible

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Google Translate API in my Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147284/how-to-use-google-translate-api-in-my-java-application)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Google Cloud Translation API, you need to have a project which has this API enabled, so you can make authenticated calls. You can set it up [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup).

Google provide a lot of sample codes, [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/samples), which you can use. The code below is used to translate a string Spanish(es) to German(de),

```
Translation translation =
    translate.translate(
        "Hola Mundo!",
        Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("es"),
        Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("de"),
        // Use "base" for standard edition, "nmt" for the premium model.
        Translate.TranslateOption.model("nmt"));

System.out.printf("TranslatedText:\nText: %s\n", translation.getTranslatedText());
```

[This article](https://medium.com/@yeksancansu/how-to-use-google-translate-api-in-android-studio-projects-7f09cae320c7) explains in details how to integrate the API within your Android Studio project, it can give you a better overview of the whole process.

Lastly, I should point out that according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing),

> Prices are pro rata (proportional and incremental). Charges are scaled to the number of characters actually provided to Cloud Translation. For example, if you send 575,000 characters for processing within a month, you are charged $1.50. The first 500,000 characters are free, and then you are charged for the additional 75,000 characters sent for detection, translation, or both.

As another alternative you can also check the [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) library, which  according to the documentation:

> Googletrans is a free and unlimited python library that implemented Google Translate API. This uses the Google Translate Ajax API to make calls to such methods as detect and translate.