# How to use Google translate for free? Maybe you have some analogs

Tags: api, translate

Good day Guys!
Sorry but I try to find out How to use Google translate for free?
THE API do not show that its free.
[just example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNC4q.png)
How are u using it?
Maybe you have some analogs..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159904/2478398

Comment: thanks a lot!! Can u say please if I have some limits of queries per day or month?

Comment: Yes it is Scott